# Find MIN value between a variable range of cells in two columns that contain TRUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Sorry if I'm not being super clear! I'm not very adept with Excel but have been making use of it lately for some analysis on financial data. I have a normal OHLC set of data and two other columns where I have some IF statements printing True or False.

How would I accomplish the following:

I want to find the minimum value in one of the OHLC columns that is in a range between where one column has a True value and the other has a True value? This range will be variable and changing depending on the distance between the two trues in each column, if they are there.

I do not need to continually do this, just on a day by day basis. I only need a formula to select this range going back, for example, where the day in my time-series begins at 10:00 each day.

sorry for being unclear, imagine this.

```
date  time  open  high  low  close  condition1  condition2  
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx   true 
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                         <--------this range
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                         <--------i want min 
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                true
```

but of course this range is variable each day, the conditions may be spaced out differently or might not have (2) true's but if it does. i want to know how to specify whatever range of cells is inbetween these two values

Comment: You tagged this question with both `excel-vba` and `excel-formula`.  Are you looking for a solution that uses either/both methods, or only one?
Also, could you post a screenshot illustrating what you need to make it easier to visualize?

Comment: I'm happy to help you through this but without example data and expected outcome it is hard to do, a simple mock up of fake data and the expected outcome in a screenshot will suffice. You can probably do this with a singe `SUMPRODUCT()` formula, `SUM() IF()` array formula or an `INDEX(), MATCH()` if you want a visual breakdown before running the total.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the interest. i plan to attatch a copy of the spreadsheet i was trying to execute this idea on, im just not around that laptop at the moment. first things first, not really anything complicated on the level of what you described. dont want to trade 'live' or anything super in-depth. just want to be able to do some data collection on price behaviour on the fly. ill add alot of comments on the spreadsheet i attatch so you can get the jist of it. and on the subject of what if the conditions switch. the second condition will be reliant on the first to show itself as true. so the only other permutation will be that condition 2 doesnt show itself. when i get around my other laptop i will add alot of comments to the spreadsheet explaining everything in fine detail and attatch it. sorry no VBA experience, although running into these problems is making me heavily consider it. I usually went about collecting the info i would like to by hand, but gathering a big sample size is tedious work. thanks again.

and on the other question you asked, i dont want to find the number of rows inbetween the range, i want to be able to specify that range in =MIN() calculation in another column.

the first condition will trigger true if price has broken the high price in a column i have in the 10:00 row which is a =MAX() calculation from 6:00-10:00 giving me the four hour high. if any of the sequential prices in the high column are >= to the 4h high price condition1 prints true. then if any of the sequential low prices after this column has printed true are <= the 6-10 high price - 0.0005 (5 points) another condition will hit True, with a third condition tracking this condition if its True and any of the sequential high prices reach back to the =max() high from 6-10 that condition will print True.

i then want to find the minimum low value that falls between where my first and last condition are true. if they are not, do nothing. and like i explained before all conditions will rely on each other to be active before the other can check for its own criteria. so the only permutations are them 'not' being active as opposed to being shuffled around in a different order

hopefully this explains it a lil before i can provide my spreadsheet

Answer (score -1):

This is a nice problem for us to look at.  I am assuming you are trading, and are looking at some sort of movement indicators at certain points in time (maybe some obscure Greeks or other functions rooted in advanced statistical analysis).  If you are looking to implement this in real-time, I highly recommend using some other programming languages (R is a great statistical programming language for the analysis of stock movement and rebalancing portfolios each day, as long as it is not time-sensitive to the nanosecond).  Speak with some of your colleagues who know HFT guys, they would be able to help you out with algorithmic trading.

However, assuming you are doing this analysis for long-term trading strategies, not HFT, we need a bit of clarification, however...

```
date  time  open  high  low  close  condition1  condition2  
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx   true 
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                        
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                         
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                true
```

You gave us this sample data.  You want the number of rows between the `TRUE` values of columns `condition1` and `condition2`.  In this case, it should return either `2` or `4` ... which of these is correct?  This will affect the writing of the code.

Also, what if your data looks like this:

```
date  time  open  high  low  close  condition1  condition2  
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                 true
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                        
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                         
xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx     true
```

In this case, do you still want to return the minimum value?  Or are you only concerned with the first case, where `condition1` is met, and *then* `condition2` is met some time after that?

Also, what if this event happens:

```
date  time  open  high  low  close  condition1  condition2  
    xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx   true 
    xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx             true           
    xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx                         
    xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx  xxxx xxxx
```

Would you like to return value `0`, or do you want the program to skip over this?

I am sorry for all of the questions, but we need to know about these corner cases if we are to help you with your VBA-related request.

Finally, do you have any VBA experience?  Have you attempted to write any yourself at this point?  If so, it would be great for you to include this to show some research and effort on your end, and for us to use as a basis to help you.